# Binding to HasValue on Nullable type with Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-toolkit

I am having trouble with this binding:

```
<sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Invoiced" Binding="{Binding SalesInvoiceId.HasValue}" />
```

The error is:
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'HasValue' property not found on '6' 'System.Int32' (HashCode=6). BindingExpression: Path='SalesInvoiceId.HasValue' DataItem='Entities.DeliveryNote' (HashCode=5034835); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]')..

The field SalesInvoiceId is on the data context for the row, all other columns bind fine.

The type of SalesInvoiceId is `int?`. And when looking at the object whilst debugging, it is shown as a `int?` so the DataGrid should not have a problem with this - yet it is refering to it as if it is just an `int`!

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks.

**Answer**

At first I tried an IValueConverter to look for the HasValue property using reflection and invoke it, unfortunatly the value parameter passed is STILL a plain old int.

I now have the following:

```
public class HasValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Invoiced" Binding="{Binding SalesInvoiceId, Converter={StaticResource HasValueConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can have that HasValue expression in the binding with Silverlight, you might have to use a converter or expose a property doing this evaluation for you and returning a bool.

Comment: I see, the problem is that I am binding the business entity (DeliveryNote) directly to the line, and adding another property would mean creating a proxy object and transporting all the values over... I wondered if there was some way to avoid this. I like Silverlight and MVVM - but sometimes it seems like a lot of hard work!

Comment: Ah, I see, a converter might still save your skin though!

Comment: Good suggestion, problem still exists in that the value passed to the IValueConverter is of type 'int'. I do not know why it is changing the value from int? to int.

Comment: Instead of depending on the Nullable<> I just check if value == null in the ValueConverter. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good stuff, glad I managed to give you the first nudge towards the solution :)